# Apple TV gen 2 will send optical audio signal when i patch it though a TOSLINK 1to2 splitter to my Bose speaker

Tags: audio

My Bose system only has one optical audio input so I added a toslink 1to2 splitter.  I can play my TV sound going through the optical audio cable to the splitter and then to my Bose system, but the Apple TV optical audio cable will not work when I put it though the splitter.  It does work if I put it directly into the optical audio input on the Bose?  What is going on?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a little more information about how your system is set up? Are you trying to set up the splitter so that BOTH audio from your tv and Apple TV go to your Bose system? If so, that won't work. Instead run the audio from the Apple TV over HDMI to the TV and then optical out from the TV to the Bose system

Answer (score 1):

You need a optical *switcher*, not a spitter. A splitter has one input and distributes to two (or more) outputs, and is not reversible.

Two possible products are available from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003C15798) and [Audio Authority](https://www.audioauthority.com/product_details/1177A/Switcher/5/1). The second does automatic switching, which may be what you're looking for.

*Disclaimer*: I have no financial or otherwise tangible connections to either Amazon.com or Audio Authority.

Comment: I disagree. Why run optical out of the Apple TV instead of running it through HDMI to the TV and then running optical out of TV? Won't that achieve the same thing without adding extra cables and buying new hardware?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion NoahL.  The problem is that we cannot get to the back of the TV.  I realized that I did need a switcher not a splitter and I have ordered one with a remote from Amazon. Thanks for your help.